# Capture several consecutive expression with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I need to capture several consecutive divs that I can recognize only with their start:

```
<div class="catched">
    something maybe with divs and more
</div>
<div class="catched">
    something else
</div>
<div class="catched">
    something else
</div>
```

However if I do `preg_match('#<div class="catched">.+?<div class="catched"#i',$html,$match)` it will only capture the first one.
I already did that, I think it's with a non-capturing group but I don't find how to do and I don't remember how I did.

Comment: Because the second div haven't `<div class="catched` after it.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: I know all that, but I also know there's a solution with regex...

Comment: Use `s` modifier and `preg_match_all`

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `HTML` parser instead:

```
<?php
$junk = <<<EOT
<div class="catched">
    something maybe with divs and more
</div>
<div class="catched">
    something else
</div>
EOT;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($junk);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divs = $xpath->query("*/div[@class='catched']");
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    echo $div->nodeValue;
}

?>
```

Which yields

```
something maybe with divs and more

something else
```

---

For a quick, dirty and error-prone solution, you could use

```
preg_match_ll('~<div class="catched">(?s)(.+?)</div>~');
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Pv1El8/1/).

Comment: The regex will not work because there are nesteds `DIV`s, from OP: `something maybe with divs and more`